# Disk Usage Forecast with KQL and Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, kql

I've been struggling past few days to create a graph for a dashboard I'm working on Azure.

The idea is to get the data collected on Perf, then use it to predict the disk usage with series_decompose_forecast.

Here is what I have right now:

```
    let DiskSpace = Perf
    | where Computer == "COMPUTERNAME" 
        and ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" 
        and InstanceName == "F:" 
        and CounterName == "% Free Space"
    | where TimeGenerated > ago(90d)
    | extend Timestamp = TimeGenerated, DiskIdentifier = InstanceName, FreeSpace = CounterValue
    | project Timestamp, DiskIdentifier, FreeSpace;
DiskSpace
    | make-series FreeSpace=max(FreeSpace) default=long(null) on Timestamp from ago(60d) to now()+24h*7*4 step 12h
    | extend FreeSpace=series_fill_backward(FreeSpace), forecast=series_decompose_forecast(FreeSpace, 7*4*2)
    | render timechart
```

The second part, the "make-series" is from an old question on stack, and I've been trying to adapt it to use for my own purposes. This query creates a graph for me, but the data returned from the forecast is null, and I'm not sure why. Any idea what I'm missing here?

Cheers, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with `default=long(0)`.

```
range timestamp from ago(55d) to now() step 4h
| extend FreeSpace = 50 + (now()-timestamp)/1d
| make-series FreeSpace=max(FreeSpace) default=long(0) on timestamp from ago(60d) to now(24h*7*4) step 12h
| extend FreeSpace=series_fill_backward(FreeSpace), forecast=series_decompose_forecast(FreeSpace, 7*4*2)
| render timechart
```